# How to get postgresql to work with sequel and jruby

Tags: ruby, postgresql, jdbc, jruby, sequel

```
require 'sequel'
require 'jdbc/postgres'
DB = Sequel.connect("jdbc:postgresql://user:pass@domain/database")
DB.tables
```

Returns:

```
....(bla bla bla stack trace bla bla bla)....
Sequel::DatabaseConnectionError: Java::OrgPostgresqlUtil::PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
...........
```

I have also tried

```
jdbc:postgresql://domain/database?user=name&pass=word
```

and got an error as well, but a different one('password requested but not provided')

ruby 1.9.3 - jruby 1.7.3

I have looked and looked, tried many code samples, but I am unable to get Sequel working
So, How do I get Sequel to interface with postgres while using jruby?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sequel passes a jdbc connection string directly to JDBC, so there is nothing Sequel-specific about it.  You probably want something like `jdbc:postgresql://domain/database?user=name&password=secret`

Comment: Thank you so much! This has been bugging me. Silly password= not pass=